# How can a get length of a string in Micorsoft Sharepoint list in o365?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm looking for a way to find the length of a string, I tried the below code which gives me a count of an array:

```
"txtContent":"="length('Some Text')"
```

But I want the length of the text, is there a way to find the length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this :

```
=indexOf('some text' + '|', '|')
```